# Calculate ArrayFormula per row in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I am trying to perform a calculation on each row using the Array Formula function. When I try to use a range A2:A it tries to perform a calculation on the entire range as opposed to per row.

Which part am I missing to calculate per row?

`={"id";ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("", TRUE,(LEFT(B2,2)),(A2*86400000)))}`

Here is the formula active in a Google Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXA_yC_beoe7UXgXZvbj9knNU8ms1MPMgLKrro4G-T0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some formulas like Textjoin won't work in an arrayformula. If the formula already takes a range, then it doesn't understand that you want it to calculate row by row. Try this formula. I got rid of the textjoin part, and just used an ampersand to join columns A and B.

> ={"id";ArrayFormula(iferror(if(A2:A="",,LEFT(B2:B,2)&(A2:A*86400000))))}

`